# What causes `ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Unknown resource type` error message?

Tags: excel-dna

I have been developing an addin and all has been going well during development, and i am now at the point that I wish to create the distributable version of the addin, which is the packed version. The packing seems like it goes ok, however, when I open the packed xll file with Excel I get the following error:

> Initialization [Error] External library could not be registered -
>   Path: packed: : ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Unknown
>   resource type. Only types 0 (Assembly), 1 (Dna file), 2 (Image) or 3
>   (Source) are valid. Parameter name: type

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include your .dna file in the question so that we can see which files are being packed (and their types)?

Answer (score 0):

[Excel-DNA only support the following resource types](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/2aa1bd9afaf76084c1d59e2330584edddb888eb1/Source/ExcelDna.Loader/AssemblyManager.cs#L123-L153):

- .NET Assembly (.dll)
- .dna file
- Image
- Source code file (.cs, .vb, etc.)
- .pdb file

The error you're see seems to be caused by the packing of a file that is not any of the types above.

Or perhaps, the version of ExcelDnaPack.exe you're running is not the same as the ExcelDna.xll that you're running.

How does your .dna file look like and what are the files being packed (and their types)?